# Amazon AWS send text messages using C#

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS account ./ server. How can I send a text message in C# from a desktop app using AWS. I can't seem to find any examples or  helpful docs.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS doesn't offer a general purpose SMS messaging platform. It's SNS product does allow SMS as one of the optional delivery methods, but its not useful in a lot of scenarios because it requires users devices to be 'subscribed' before getting text messages.

A better choice for a general purpose SMS messaging solution is going to be Twilio or Clickatel or other similar vendors - both of those can easily send general purpose/custom SMS messages to any cell phone (in countries they support), without the user previously subscribing to the service, using C# from a desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

You need REST API hosted on your AWS EC2. Then you create desktop application that call http request to that service.

Comment: What is the service.. can it send a SMS to any carrier?

Comment: You need to create a website that expose that WEB REST API. That website must be hosted on IIS in your EC2. That REST API,at the backend calling AWS messaging service (is about SMS text ?). On desktop you create apps that use clientside http request to that REST API. Other issue is how to secure your REST API service.